# Defining the constructor

Tags: android, constructor

Error in TapkeysActivity.java at "tapdb hon = new tapdb(this);" . It tell to define the constructor tapdb(new View.OnClickListener(){}).  Please tell me how to define the constructor . Related code is as follows:

TapkeysActivity.java

```
package com.android.tusway;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TapkeysActivity extends Activity  {


private EditText et;
private Button b1,b2,b3,b4,bspace;
private String stringDb="";
private TextView tv;


private void updateTextField() {
    tv.setText(this.stringDb);


}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // adjusting key regarding window sizes

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bspace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btspace);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringDb += "1";
                updateTextField();  

            }
        });


        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringDb += "2";
                updateTextField();  

            }
        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringDb += "3";
                updateTextField();  

            }
        });

        b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringDb += "4";
                updateTextField();  

            }
        });

        bspace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringDb += " ";
                updateTextField();


                long l = Long.parseLong(stringDb);
                tapdb hon = new tapdb(this);
                hon.open();
                String returnedWord = hon.getWord(l);

                hon.close();


                et.setText(returnedWord);


            }
        });

}
   }
```

tapdb.java

```
 package com.android.tusway;



 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



 public class tapdb {

public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_CODE="key_code";
public static final String KEY_WORD="word";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="tapdatabase";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE="tapData";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREAMENT,"+
                KEY_WORD + "TEXT NOT NULL" +
                KEY_CODE + "LONG);"

        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
public tapdb (Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
  }


public tapdb open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();

}





public String getWord(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORD, KEY_CODE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String hotness = c.getString(1);

            return hotness;
    }


    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
tapdb hon = new tapdb(this);
```

To

```
tapdb hon = new tapdb(TapkeysActivity.this);
```

or to

```
tapdb hon = new tapdb(v.getContext());
```

When you are inside an anonymous inner class, `this` does not refer to the Actviity instance (in this case, since you are in an `OnClickListener`, `this` refers to your `OnClickListener` instance) and so, you must explictly access it via `TapkeysActivity.this` or via `v.getContext()`.

Comment: To clarify- when you call `new tapdb(this);`, you are doing so within your `OnClickListener`. Thus `this` refers to the OnClickListener you are creating, not your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line ,

```
tapdb hon = new tapdb(this);
```

with

```
tapdb hon = new tapdb(TapkeysActivity.this);
```